# while is not recognized (system call-c)

Tags: loops, while-loop, enter

i have a little problem. i have this code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/stat.h> // serve per le FIFO
#include <fcntl.h> // serve per la open
#include <stdbool.h>
#define BUF_SIZE 100

int main (int argc,char *argv[]){

----definition of variables----

if (argc > 3) {
    printf("Errore troppi argomenti da riga di start\n");
    return -1;
}

if (argc < 2) {
    printf("Errore pochi argomenti da riga di start\n"); 
    return -1;
}

if(argc == 3){
    pathServer=argv[1];
    pathClient=argv[2];
    printf("Ho stampato da riga di comando %d parametri.\n", argc);
}

if(argc == 2){
    pathServer=argv[1];
    printf("Ho stampato da riga di comando %d parametri.\n", argc);
}

if((mkfifo(pathClient, S_IWUSR | S_IRUSR)) < 0){ 
printf("Errore. FifoClient non creata.\n");
return -1;
}

fifoServer=open(pathServer, O_WRONLY);
write(fifoServer, pathClient, strlen(pathClient));
fifoClient=open(pathClient, O_RDONLY);

while(contr1) {
    printf ("Inserisci comando da eseguire:\n");
(other code)
}
```

the program does not go into the first while.
it do all control before while and afther that the terminal doesnt show nothing
i dont know why, please help me

Comment: where are you intializing contr1??

Comment: in ----definition of variables---- i do this: 
bool contr1=true;

Comment: what are  pathServer=argv[1];
    pathClient=argv[2];

Comment: if both of them are char * , then you will need an array or memory to store the variables

Answer (score 0):

Please clarify your problem a bit before we can answer this.

Do you mean it not recognise the first `if`  or the first `while`? If you meant the `while`, then please give some advice about the variable `contr1` in its condition. Where it comes from? What modifies its value?